# How can I set locale for a spreadsheet while uploading it to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using [this template](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) to upload file to GDrive:

```
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/report.csv");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/csv", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
    .setFields("id")
    .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

I've tried to use Google Sheets API and send a requests to update a locale:

```
List<Request> requests = Collections.singletonList(
        new Request().setUpdateSpreadsheetProperties(
                new UpdateSpreadsheetPropertiesRequest()
                        .setFields("locale")
                        .setProperties(
                                new SpreadsheetProperties()
                                        .setLocale("en_US")
                        )
        )
);
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
requestBody.setRequests(requests);
requestBody.setIncludeSpreadsheetInResponse(false);

Sheets.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate updateLocaleRequest = sheets.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, requestBody);
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = updateLocaleRequest.execute();
```

But I want to set a locale **when uploading a file**.

Comment: AFAIK, that is the only way to do it since you are using Drive API your option to set properties will be limited. But if you'll create a sheet using Sheets API you can set the Locale upon creation since the API focuses on sheets functionalities. Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I upload that spreadsheet to Google Drive then?

Comment: How about this method? Unfortunately, Drive API has no properties for modifying spreadsheet parameters, while uploading a file. This is the same answer with Mr.Rebot. So, as a workaround, for example, 1. Read csv data from a file. 2. Create a new spreadsheet using sheets.spreadsheets.create of Sheets API. At that time, it adds ``{"properties": {"locale": "en_US"}}`` and ``{"sheets": [{"data": [ ### CSV data ### ]}]}`` for the request body. I think that by this, you can upload CSV data with ``locale`` as a new spreadsheet.

Comment: Looks good to me. How can I convert `String` (CSV data) to `GridData` though?